# How i can add cron entry without time using chef

Tags: apache-flex, cron, chef-infra

Via cookbook recipe i want to add crontab entry which will help me to start application whenever my VM will restart so with entry i don't want to specify anytime i tried with this code:-

```
cron 'Reboot_entry' do
  user node['aem_vm_cookbook']['owner']['user']
  command '@reboot /bin/rm -f /ebiz/aem/crx-quickstart/conf/cq.pid ; source /etc/profile.d/aemprofile.sh > /dev/null ; /ebiz/aem/crx-quickstart/bin/start > /ebiz/aem/crx-quickstart/logs/reboot.log 2>&1'
end
```

For this i did not specify anytime but it is creating entry with * mark which looks like this:-

```
* * * * * @reboot /bin/rm -f /ebiz/aem/crx-quickstart/conf/cq.pid ; source /etc/profile.d/aemprofile.sh > /dev/null ; /ebiz/aem/crx-quickstart/bin/start > /ebiz/aem/crx-quickstart/logs/reboot.log 2>&1
```

This entry is working fine when VM restart but the problem it is executing every minute and if i am stopping application for some work it will start after one minute.I just want to work this reboot entry only for VM restart. If i am removing all stars this is working fine.

So i don't need any * while adding this cron entry.

Answer (score 1):

The `time` property of the [cron resource](https://docs.chef.io/resources/cron/) takes special times such as `@reboot` (`:reboot`). So your resource should be like:

```rb
cron 'Reboot_entry' do
  command '/bin/rm -f /ebiz/aem/crx-quickstart/conf/cq.pid ; source /etc/profile.d/aemprofile.sh > /dev/null ; /ebiz/aem/crx-quickstart/bin/start > /ebiz/aem/crx-quickstart/logs/reboot.log 2>&1'
  user node['aem_vm_cookbook']['owner']['user']
  time :reboot
end
```